# How to fix flex div to take full height as its parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, onclick, bootstrap-5

[image]

[image]

[image]
Actually, I want to trigger a onClick on the body where discussion and icons are positioned. However, onClick on the body is not having any problems. The spacing area, however, is where it breaks. I wish to close this gap. but are unable to. Is there a fix for the space that would allow me to make the entire body clickable?

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary mt-2 " style="max-width: 400px ;  height: 130px;">
        <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
          <a href="">Somecontent from a map</a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-strentch " onclick="alert('hey')">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2 flex-1 d-inline-block"  >
            <text class="bg-warning "> discussed </text>
            <div  onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `onclick div`, you are not obliged to use flex position.
You can add `h-100` to get 100% height

You can use this :

```html
<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary mt-2 " style="max-width: 400px ;  height: 130px;">
        <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
          <a href="">Somecontent from a map</a>
        </div>
        <div class="h-100 " onclick="alert('hey')">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2 flex-1 d-inline-block"  >
            <text class="bg-warning "> discussed </text>
            <div  onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
  </body>
```

Comment: You rock! I want to display the content of two divs in the same location. Since the text in the first div is longer and has an impact on where the body content is positioned, the two divs do not look alike. Please see the SS that I have attached.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your question very well :/

Comment: I asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199217/how-to-prevent-text-from-prevent-the-others-elements. Can you please go through it. I shall be very thankful to you