# how to prevent text from changing the height of other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

[image]

I have two divs and want to display the content of both divs in the same location. Since the text in the first div is longer and has an impact on where the body content is positioned, the two divs do not look alike.I want the position of second div body content like first div body content. Please see the SS that I have attached.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body style="padding: 40px">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary " style="max-width: 400px ; height: 130px ">
      <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
        <a href="">Somecontent from a map function here dsdsadsadsffffffff</a>
      </div>
      <div class="h-100">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2" onclick="alert('hey')" >
          <text class="bg-warning"> discussed </text>
          <div  onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary mt-2 " style="max-width: 400px ;  height: 130px;">
        <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
          <a href="">Somecontent from a map</a>
        </div>
        <div class="h-100" onclick="alert('hey')">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2"  >
            <text class="bg-warning"> discussed </text>
            <div  onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your static `height`'s then use the `.py-3` class for `1rem` of vertical `padding` on your `.h-100` div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body style="padding: 40px">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary " style="max-width: 400px; height: 140px;">
    <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
      <a href="">Somecontent from a map function here dsdsadsadsffffffff</a>
    </div>
    <div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2 w-100" onclick="alert('hey')">
        <text class="bg-warning"> discussed </text>
        <div onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary mt-2 " style="max-width: 400px; height: 140px;">
    <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center py-3">
      <a href="">Somecontent from a map</a>
    </div>
    <div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" onclick="alert('hey')">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2 w-100">
        <text class="bg-warning"> discussed </text>
        <div onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it is cool now. But the height of the div is still different. The first div is of 154px and second one is 130px. I want the height same. Position of body content is looking perfect

Comment: @sohaib how do you expect to have them to be the same `height` and look exactly the same when there is more content in one vs. the other?

Comment: The cards will look weird.I want the height of div same. The body content  should have the same padding from bottom but from top it can be different because of more content

Comment: @sohaib see edits, about the best you can do with the requirement of them matching heights and sharing the same white space.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the height, the only thing I can see is to cut the text or to increase the width or your elements

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
 <style>
span {
 width : 100%;
 word-break: break-all;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body style="padding: 40px">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary " style="max-width: 400px ; height: 130px ">
      <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
        <a href=""><span>Somecontent from a map function here dsdsadsadsffffffff<span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="h-100">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2" onclick="alert('hey')" >
          <text class="bg-warning"> discussed </text>
          <div  onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-primary mt-2 " style="max-width: 400px ;  height: 130px;">
        <div class="w-100 bg-warning text-center p-2">
          <a href="">Somecontent from a map</a>
        </div>
        <div class="h-100" onclick="alert('hey')">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch justify-content-between pt-4 pb-2 px-2"  >
            <text class="bg-warning"> discussed </text>
            <div  onclick="alert('hey click me')">icons here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All you did was put the text on one line.

Comment: There is really no other way to keep the same height knowing that the content is larger for one of the elements. One of the only ways is to put on a line or enlarge the default size.